# django database can not get the updated data

Tags: django-models

our client updates the database. Then the mysql database updated, server should read the updated value from database at that moment. But its not happening. To read the updated value from the database, I have to restart the server. Then I see the updated values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart the database if you update it. Maybe your update misses the final COMMIT?

If you use SQL with connection.execute() you need to call commit_unless_managed() at the end.